# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.setLooping(boolean)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to Android and I am making an Battery Alert Application in which their is a point where user select Ringtone and i save the Path of that Ringtone in Shared Preference as a string and getting that ringtone in my Service class in Media player. I am Getting the Path in Toast but still i am having null object reference in my MediaPlayer Object i don't understand what i am doing Wrong. Here my Code

This is My class where i am calling my RingtoneManager

```
  final Uri currentTone=
                        RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(Setting.this,
                                RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
                Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
                intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
                intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Tone");
                intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, currentTone);
                intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
                intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 999);`
```

And then calling it onActivityResult Method and saving the Path in Shared Preference the Path in Toast look like this "internal/audio/media/39"

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 999 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);

        Toast.makeText(Setting.this, "" + uri.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        SharedPreferences tune2 = getSharedPreferences("tuneforlow", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editortune2 = tune2.edit();
        editortune2.putString("lowpath", uri.getPath().toString());
        editortune2.commit();
     }`
```

After that calling the Shared Preference in my Service Class

```
      public static MediaPlayer alertsound;
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    
    SharedPreferences t2 =getSharedPreferences("tuneforlow", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String tune2 = t2.getString("lowpath","");
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+tune2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   Uri url =  Uri.parse(tune2);
   if(tune2.equals("")) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "Not " +url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       alertsound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Settings.System.CONTENT_URI);

    }else{
       Toast.makeText(this, "yes" +url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       alertsound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), url);
    }

    alertsound.setLooping(true);
}`
```

I am Getting the Error in alertsound as null object reference but i am getting the path in Toast.

Comment: Saving uri.getPath() does not make sense as it is no file system path. Save uri.toString() instead. Then you can later get your uri back. What is it that you wanna do with the uri later?

Comment: @blackapps Thank you So much. That worked. I was trying to find the solution for hours but it was my silly mistake. Thank You so so much. God Bless You.